# Code is showing in Android Studio designer but not in Emulator

Tags: android

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/WhiteBackground"
    tools:context=".Game">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cards_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="620dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/as"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ah"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ad"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ac, ad, ah and as each correspond to a card of an ace of a certain suit. In the designer it shows me this:
[Designer Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9xhT.png)

How ever the emulator is blank: [Emulator Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avrhh.png)

Is the problem with one of the layouts?
Why is the emulator blank and how can this be fixed?

If you could help me I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: Set height of linearlayout to match-parent instead of android:layout_height="100dp"

Comment: You might want to use RecyclerView and maybe GridLayout instead of adding the images this way

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I tried that now and it still doesn't show. I tried deleting the margins of the LinearLayout and doing what you said they still don't show up

Comment: Please show your full activity code. I'm run your layout (only add close tag for constraint layout) and everything is fine. More over, margins doesn't work because you user ConstraintLayout with ReletiveLayout comands that just ignores.